# Google Keep backed with Google Calendar

Tags: google-tasks, google-keep, google-calendar-reminders

I use Google Keep to remember tasks to be done and want to store them in Google Calendar.
Sometimes I use Google Now to set reminder, however they go [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=show%20reminders).

I want consistent look of tasks, events, and reminders, preferably in Calendar.
How do I find all these together? I wish to keep record of past events/tasks too.

Is there any way to delegate the tasks or reminders to friend? Is there any way to share tasklist with Family Circle? It would be useful to share tasks like, **pay telephone bill, go to airport to pick up guest** with family circle, whoever completes/takes can mark it as over/taken. So no two attempt the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of Google Calendar Android app shows all your reminders from Google Now and Keep as well.
([Google Support](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6285327))

For your second question, you could create a checklist/tasklist on Keep and share it with your friends or family.
([Google Support](https://support.google.com/keep/answer/6101196))